# Python: Import "fake_useragent" could not be resolved

Tags: python

Начал изучать парсинг на питоне и появилась необходимость использовать `fake_useragent`, при его импорте он подчеркивается желтой линией

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

установленная версия fake_useragent самая новая.

Помогите пожалуйста!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Наведя мышь на подчеркнутое - можно получить более подробную информацию. Не разберетесь в ней - отправьте сюда.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Сегодня зашёл все работает без ошибок, хотя ничего не менялось

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблема, только с другим модулем, как выяснилось просто слетел выбранный ранее интерпретатор (дело было в VS Code).
Решилось тоже соответственно тоже довольно просто: вид - палитра команд или (Ctrl + Shift + P) и в поиске Python Select Interpreter (выбрать интерпретатор) и далее выбираем нужный (который используется для проекта).
Соответственно если проект в виртуалке выбираем с пометкой vevn(ну или какое имя придумали ранее для папки с виртуалкой), если он пропал из выборки выбираем меню добавления (то что с +) и указываем путь.
Если в глобалке, то просто берем нужную версию.